# best database type to use with Trac

Tags: trac

I am in need to install trac on a cloud server which runs centos.

What is the best database type to use? I would like to install trac with mysql but the [trac website](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/MySqlDb) says:

> "There are also a couple of #KnownIssues and supporting this database
>   has proven to be painful at times."

I am afraid to use SQLite as SQLite is not good for larger databases.  Can some one give me an idea of the best database type for trac?

much appreciated

Comment: Trac comes in different flavors?

Comment: what is meant is that what are the best stuff I can install trac? sqllite / mysql / or postgres ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any flavor has both, it's fans and opponents. It's [rather undisputed](http://howfuckedismydatabase.com/mysql/), that [MySQL has it's weaknesses, but PROs too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332194).

Answering these questions to yourself may help:

- Do you already use some flavor of RDBMS, that is supported by Trac? If YES, use that.
- What is a *large* database to you?

  - < 10.000 tickets and wiki pages, rarely [concurrent transactions](http://sqlite.org/faq.html#q19): SQLite will handle this well, don't [care for something else](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html).
  - 'more': You may profit from a full-fledged RDBMS, so use PostgreSQL.
- Could I delegate database management? If YES, you'll find the seamless, well tested environment upgrade with automatic db backup, that is only provided for SQLite, less important.

Comment: I may post some more criteria as my time permits, but this may give you already some pointers.

Comment: thanks for the very descriptive answer